# API request not getting the response from the Android application, while same is working from the web application

Tags: android, angular, api, server, firewall

I have an web application which is developed in to Angualr js 1, this application url, i called in to Android webview to generate .apk file of Angular application. From .apk file i am sending one request to the external server that need to give me some response from the server , but when i am sending request from .apk i am not getting any response for this api.

- It gives me the response error in few seconds.
- The Same API if i fired from the web browser(Chrom Version 71.0.3578.98) its giving me the exact ouput.
- But when i fired it from .apk file i am not getting any response that means it fails.
- Provided the firewall access for both source and destination ip's.

what will be the possible causes, why i am not getting any response from .apk file?

Comment: do you get any error code or something?

Comment: Add manifest file code

Comment: @urvishran I called these two function success and fail                         .then(function successCallback(response) { } & function errorCallback(response) {} it comes to the errorCallback after few seconds,  it doesn't return any code.

Comment: will you please share the code?

Comment: @Urvishrana code is here simple ajax call is here,  
$scope.DownloadAPP=function(){
    $http({
    method  : 'GET',       
          url:"API URL",    
    })
     //.then(function(response){
      .then(function successCallback(response) {  
     
     },    
    function errorCallback(response) {
    $scope.loading = false;  
                  alert("Sorry, Unable to process request"+link);
             }); 
  }
 }

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier, yes i given it, others API's are working fine.